# express, i18next-node and setLng

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express and i18next-node. I have a problem when I try to change the lang inside my route. I have no problem if I put it on the url.
My init:

```
i18n.init({
 saveMissing: true,  
 sendMissingTo : 'all', 
 fallbackLng : 'it-IT',   
 ignoreRoutes: ['img/', 'public/', 'css/', 'js/'],
 useCookie: true,
 debug: true
});
```

in my route (and I saw [u18next node setLng seems that doesn´t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098492/u18next-node-setlng-seems-that-doesn%C2%B4t-work)) I have

```
var theLang = 'fr-FR';
console.log(req.i18n.lng());  // this gives me it-IT
req.i18n.setLng(theLang);   // I thouth this would change the lang to fr-FR
console.log('now I have ' +theLang+ ' '+ i18n.lng());
```

result is fr-FR it-IT

why ? How can I change it ? I don't have a session yet, this is the first page the user get, depending on the url (which does not have the lang), I chose the language. 
What should I do ? thanks

Comment: My impression is that when the second console.log is called, the lang is not yet set. What can I do to be sure that it is set before I continue ?

Comment: solved loading all the langs during the initialization

Answer (score 0):

setLng has a callback, try:

```
req.i18n.setLng(theLang, function(){
    console.log('now I have ' +theLang+ ' '+ i18n.lng());
});
```